# Remove duplicates in rows, insert NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

I didn't see any simillar question and it might be useful for others.
I'd like to remove duplicates in rows and insert NAs instead.
Ok, quick example, let's create a df:

```
v1 <- c('A','D','F')
v2 <- c('A','D','G')
v3 <- c('B','E','F')
v4 <- c('C', NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4)

> df
  v1 v2 v3   v4
1  A  A  B    C
2  D  D  E <NA>
3  F  G  F <NA>
```

Desired result:

```
> df
  v1 v2 v3     v4
1  A  B  C   <NA>
2  D  E <NA> <NA>
3  F  G <NA> <NA>
```

Ok, I tried to solve this by, extracting each row from df then `unique()` and then put it back into df. Here's example for one row but ut doesn't work. If it will, I'll run some apply to each row.

```
df[1,] <- unique(as.character(unlist(df[1,])))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to loop through the rows, `replace` the `duplicated` elements with `NA`, concatenate (`c`) the non-NA elements with the 'NA' elements, transpose (`t`) the dataset and convert to `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
        x1 <- replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)
        c(x1[!is.na(x1)], x1[is.na(x1)])})))
#  V1 V2   V3   V4
#1  A  B    C <NA>
#2  D  E <NA> <NA>
#3  F  G <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, it works great, thank you for the explanation